# How can I read Bluetooth Classic RSSI without connection?

Tags: c#, bluetooth

Is there any way to read Bluetooth Classic RSSI in Microsoft Bluetooth Stack?

I'm looking for the solution how I can read Bluetooth Classic RSSI without connection. I tried some ways: inthehand, WinApi, or other console programs. And I looked these up, but I cannot find any solution.

Anything is fine, C# code, console program, or other else. Please tell me how I can read RSSI, or cannot.

Using Visual Studio, Windows 11 x64.

Comment: It is partially possible. You can connect to SDP and then read RSSI. Bluetooth Framework provides such feature. If device is not connected it connects to in on service level, reads  RSSI value and then disconnects. Actualy it is not driver limitation but Bluetooth itself.

Comment: The O/P has been explicit in this, asking for a way to do this *(cit.)* "without connection" - will this work without initialising an SDP-service layer by the app connecting the said device? No, it will not, which is not meeting the asked question, I guess, is it?

Answer (score 0):

According to 32Feet's creator - https://github.com/inthehand/32feet/wiki/Peer-Device-Information

> This property is not supported on desktop Windows with the Microsoft stack since there is no native API for it. It is supported on WM with the Microsoft stack (though only on the WM6 platform, devices known to support it include the HTC Trinity and the Symbol MC35). It is generally supported on the other stacks (is supported on Widcomm, BlueSoleil, Bluetopia).
>
> The Bluetooth commands used for the Rssi and ClassOfDevice properties require an open connection to the target device, although the CoD value is also read at discovery time and if is possible to get the RSSI value at discovery in later Bluetooth versions but no stack supports that as far as we know. For most platforms we don't automatically form a connection when the Rssi and ClassOfDevice properties are used, so they will fail if there's no open connection. On MSFT+WM (Microsoft stack on Windows Mobile/CE) we will internally attempt to form a (ACL) connection to allow the native API to work, thus if the device is not in range the property will take a long time to return.

So no, this is not natively supported. However you can test if a device is in range instead;

https://github.com/inthehand/32feet/wiki/Testing-if-a-device-is-in-range

Comment: Thanks for you reply.
Then I'm gonna find other way that use other Bluetooth Stack, like BlueZ or something.

Comment: @thko You can do what you need with MS stack.

Answer (score -1):

> **C :** *"(...) any way to read Bluetooth Classic RSSI in Microsoft Bluetooth Stack?"*

As a last resort, given the W11 x64 host is RAM/CPU-rich system, one may always launch a Virtual Machine ( any good HyperVisor with virtualised handling USB devices, be it Windows-ports of VirtualBox, VmWare Player (using exactly this strategy since VmWare WorkStation v.1.0 back in early 90-ies, yeah, the time is running soo fast) )

Using this, one may easily read RSSI values from linux commandline tools available since ever.

Another option is to host a BT-device on an Arduino-alike micro-controller board, which can similarly to the linux-hosted device control, read and report the actual RSSI data to the W11 host via the micro-controller board USB-interconnect, typically emulating a serial tty-dev character-I/O for the W11 side. Again, a cheap & stable, immediate solution.

If surprised by going this way, just take the cost of a USB-BT device and the cost of time/efforts/nightmares with code-refactoring after swapped BT-stacks, W-xy updates/upgrades etc. Using this strategy of reading an RSSI-value via an "exo-system" is sure to work now & forever, like reading data from an RSS-feed or a socket.

```
#hcitool rssi FF:EE:DD:CC:BB:AA // rpt'd RSSI on linux iPAQ handheld since 2003
```

---

```
#./btmon &
# hcitool lescan               // rpts RSII on Low Energy devices
```

as

```
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 12                                                                                  
      LE Advertising Report (0x02)
        ...
        Event type: Scan response - SCAN_RSP (0x04)
        Address type: Public (0x00)
        Address: FF:EE:DD:CC:BB:AA (<aVendorName>)
        Data length: 0
        ***RSSI: -31 dBm (0xde)***
FF:EE:DD:CC:BB:AA <aMobileTerminalDeviceName>
```

Cool & sure, immediate result. That's exciting ( not only after all other options failed ), isn't it?

Need to extend it? Feel free to do so, it is opensourced :

```
/* Read RSSI */

static struct option rssi_options[] = {
    { "help",   0, 0, 'h' },
    { 0, 0, 0, 0 }
};

static const char *rssi_help =
    "Usage:\n"
    "\trssi <bdaddr>\n";

static void cmd_rssi(int dev_id, int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct hci_conn_info_req *cr;
    bdaddr_t bdaddr;
    int8_t rssi;
    int opt, dd;

    for_each_opt(opt, rssi_options, NULL) {
        switch (opt) {
        default:
            printf("%s", rssi_help);
            return;
        }
    }
    helper_arg(1, 1, &argc, &argv, rssi_help);

    str2ba(argv[0], &bdaddr);

    if (dev_id < 0) {
        dev_id = hci_for_each_dev(HCI_UP, find_conn, (long) &bdaddr);
        if (dev_id < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Not connected.\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    dd = hci_open_dev(dev_id);
    if (dd < 0) {
        perror("HCI device open failed");
        exit(1);
    }

    cr = malloc(sizeof(*cr) + sizeof(struct hci_conn_info));
    if (!cr) {
        perror("Can't allocate memory");
        exit(1);
    }

    bacpy(&cr->bdaddr, &bdaddr);
    cr->type = ACL_LINK;
    if (ioctl(dd, HCIGETCONNINFO, (unsigned long) cr) < 0) {
        perror("Get connection info failed");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (hci_read_rssi(dd, htobs(cr->conn_info->handle), &rssi, 1000) < 0) {
        perror("Read RSSI failed");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("RSSI return value: %d\n", rssi);

    free(cr);

    hci_close_dev(dd);
}
```

[incl. RFC-s](https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-bluetooth/msg15044.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it seems about Bluetooth LE. I cannot use this one because I'm looking for about Bluetooth Classic RSSI.

Comment: No, the LE part was added as a just proof of this principle working both for the classic & LE variants ( after a solution hating downvote "rated" a solution working as a charm since 2003+ on many devices, like the said COMPAQ iPAQ re-flashed with linux instead of handheld WinCE and many other platforms, embedded hardware incl.'d ). I used BT RSSI scanners even on Symbian S60 mobile devices, so definitely not limited to BT LE, which has appeared some years later, after I started using this method as a universal way how to separate concerns ( BT scan is remote from desktop app / stack chosen )

Comment: @thko for details see https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76321674/revisions